# Assign Stored Procedure's OUTPUT param within dynamic query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

With regard to this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test
    (@outparam int OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(1000)

    SET @SQL = '
    DECLARE @outparam int
    IF (1=0)
        PRINT ''do something here. I use dynamic stuff in IF and in here ''
    ELSE IF (1=0)
        PRINT ''do something here. I use dynamic stuff in IF and in here ''
    ELSE if (1=1)
    BEGIN
        SET @outparam = 5
    END
    '

    EXEC (@SQL)
END
```

I need `@outparam` to be assigned inside dynamic query, because there where all the logic lives.

It doesn't work. And I see why, but I don't know how to fix it

```
DECLARE @out int
EXEC Test @outparam = @out OUTPUT

SELECT @out
```

Comment: You need to use [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - there are examples there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DaleK this works

```
CREATE procedure Test

(
    @outparam int OUTPUT
)
as

BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @SQL = '
IF (1=0)
    print ''do something here. i use dynamic stuff in IF and in here ''
ELSE IF (1=0)
    print ''do something here. i use dynamic stuff in IF and in here ''
ELSE if (1=1)
BEGIN
    SET @outparam = 5
END
'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
N'@outparam VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT',
@outparam OUTPUT;
END
```